# Make <li> active with includes using PHP and CSS

Tags: php, css, class, menu, include

I use these files as base for my website:

The `menu.php`:

```
$p = $_GET['p'];

switch($p)
{
    case "home":
        $p = "page/home.php";
    break;

    case "customers":
        $p = "page/customers.php";
    break;

    default:
        $p = "page/home.php";
    break;
}

<ul id='nav'>

   <li>Title</li>
    <ul>
        <li class="nav active"><a href="?p=home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="?p=customers">Customers</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

The `default.php`:

```
<body>
 <div id='navcontainer'>
  <?php include ("menu.php"); ?>
 </div>

<div id='content'>
 <?php include ($p); ?>
</div>
```

The `style.css`:

```
#navcontainer {margin:0; padding:0; width:220px;float:left;}
#nav li {background:#36393D; color:#fff; padding:5px 3px 5px 20px; margin:4px;border-left:5px solid #3F4C6B;}
#nav ul li{display:block; padding:3px; background:#fff; color:#000;border:none; padding:3px 0 3px 30px;}
#nav ul li:hover, #nav ul li.active {background:#eee; cursor:pointer; border-left:5px solid #4096EE;padding:3px 0 3px 25px;}
#nav ul li a {text-decoration:none; color:#000;}
```

The `home.php` and all pages:

```
<p>Hello world!</p>
```

I wonder if it is possible to get my `menu.php` to switch class to `nav active`on the `<li>` items based on what page is currently visited.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is possible with javascript too.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using just php, you can create an extra variable

```
<?php
  $p = $_GET['p'];
  $currentPageId = 0;

  switch($p)
  {
    case "home":
        $p = "page/home.php";
        $currentPageId = 1;    
    break;

    case "customers":
        $p = "page/customers.php";
        $currentPageId = 2;    
    break;

    default:
        $p = "page/home.php";
        $currentPageId = 1;    
    break;
  }
?>

<ul id='nav'>

   <li>Title</li>
    <ul>
        <li <?php if($currentPageId == 1) { echo 'class="nav active"'; } ?> ><a href="?p=home">Home</a></li>
        <li <?php if($currentPageId == 2) { echo 'class="nav active"'; } ?> ><a href="?p=customers">Customers</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give some id in REQUEST and then add:

```
$id = $_GET['id']
```

then

```
<li <?php if($id == your_id){ echo "class='nav visited'";} ?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get

```
$p = $_GET['p'];
```

to work. What worked for me was

```
$p = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```